# Redirect 301 specific page alongside all pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm currently using this code to redirect all request to `index.php`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

While having this universal code, how can I specify an individual redirect?

E.g.,
`Redirect 301 /foo http://example.com/foo-bar`

Comment: The .htaccess is processed from the top down. Place that redirect above the current block you have.

Comment: @slapyo I tried that and it kinda works but I am getting query string in the URL e.g., it redirects to `http://example.com/foo-bar?get=foo` instead of just `http://example.com/foo-bar`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^foo$ /foo-bar [R=301,L]` The L flag should cause it to stop and not continue down the .htaccess file. A nice tool for testing htaccess and seeing what rule is being used or not is http://htaccess.mwl.be

Comment: @slapyo Hmm, I have a weird issue, it works with Chrome and IE but not with FF. It still includes `?get=foo` in FF. Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cache?

Comment: @slapyo Works now! Put your comment as an answer and I will accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this above your current set of rules. The `L` flag will cause Apache to stop processing the rest of the .htaccess file. Also be sure to clear your browser cache.

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ /foo-bar [R=301,L]
```

A nice tool for testing .htaccess files can be found here http://htaccess.mwl.be/